# How to solve Access Control Exception in java applet

Tags: java, exception, applet

I am running a java applet in browser which is showing  the following error:

AccessControlException

access denied("java.io.FilePermission""image.jpg""read")

How ro resolve this. The applet is running fine with appletviewer

this is the associated code:

```
    p1=new JPanel();

    titleicon=new ImageIcon("image.jpg");
    img=new JLabel(titleicon);
    p1.add(img);
```

This is the permission granted:

```
grant codeBase "file:///C:/project/appcode_game3.htm" {
  permission java.io.FilePermission "<<ALL FILES>>", "read";
};
```

Comment: did you setup the policy as mentioned here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/tour1/step2.html

Comment: yes but its still the same problem

Comment: share some piece of code. How are you reading it?

Comment: `titleicon=new ImageIcon("image.jpg");`  Applets and files mix like oil and water (i.e. 'not at all').  Load the image by URL.

Comment: did that too..still same error